How to make Oh-My-Zsh perform tab completion with files for Git?
It works fine with other commands. For example, ls + Tab displays options appropriately. However, when I do something like git add ./sr + Tab it doesn't autocomplete the src directory that I'm targeting.
Is there a way to configure this?
I've tried doing the following:

echo 'autoload -Uz compinit && compinit' >> ~/.zshrc && . ~/.zshrc as introduced in this answer.
Adding autoload -Uz compinit && compinit to my .zshrc file as suggested in this answer.

but neither have worked.

Edit
After some more inspection it seems like the autocompletion isn't working when I try to use relative path syntax.
For example, if I had the following project structure:
project/
├── server/
│   └── main.py
└── client.py

Then:

git add cli + Tab autocompletes to git add client.py.
git add ./cli + Tab does not autocomplete to git add ./client.py.


does git ad + Tab completes the add?

have you tried reproducing with bash before assuming the issue is with oh-my-zsh?
seems to me your files are not tracked

@Fravadona Yes, git ad + Tab autocompletes to git add.

@Sarkis The files are tracked, but after reading your comment come to think of it autocompletion doesn't work when I'm trying to use relative path syntax with folders. I'll add this detail into my question.

As git add ./cli completion works in bash but not in zsh, you've probably found a bug in one or the other
